Google Fit and Health Connect sync
I have a mobile app that retrieves data for steps and distance from google health connect.
The app reads data correctly but google fit doesn't sync automatically with health connect until i open google fit. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is no way to know that provider app like google fit and samsung health are writing data to health connect in real time. some of provider apps like google fit doesn't work in realtime it takes some time to write data in health connect and ultimately your app is fetching data from health connect so it might show steps and distance with some delay.
Another case : it might be possible that google fit is writing data to health connect and your app might have some glitch.
If every thing is fine at your end then check the entry in health connect app. from apps list you can find health connect app>activity>steps>see all entries.
Hope this code can help in i am using this code to precisely fetching steps :
    suspend fun getStepsToday(
    healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient
): Long {
    var totalSteps = 0L
    val now = LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MAX)
    val startTime = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay()
    try {
        Timber.d("start_time:::$startTime")
        Timber.d("end_time:::$now")
        val response =
            healthConnectClient.aggregateGroupByPeriod(
                AggregateGroupByPeriodRequest(
                    metrics = setOf(StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL),
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, now),
                    timeRangeSlicer = Period.ofDays(1)
                )
            )

        for (monthlyResult in response) {
            if (monthlyResult.result != null) {
                totalSteps = monthlyResult.result[StepsRecord.COUNT_TOTAL]!!
            }

            Timber.d("total_steps_:::$totalSteps")
        }
        return totalSteps
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Run error handling here
        Timber.e(e, "Error getting steps")
    }

    return totalSteps
}


How does this code-of-wall addresses the issue? Please explain

This code can help to get precise steps if any glitch in app fetching steps.  however text is self explaining the issue of google fit is writing steps data to health connect.

How? Please clarify in the answer. Code-only answers are not good answers. The text you've added above the code is just speculation. You have any sources to back this up? Please keep in mind you are not only posting answers for OP, but also for future readers, who are maybe less experienced than you

OP didn't even attach any code. How do you know that OP will know where and how to use this code? Does OP even use Timber?
